# Referencing Dictionary's inside of Dictionary's inside of Dictionary's excel - VBA Object Required Error

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

Right so I have an excel program that loops through multiple pdfs and extracts data from them. In order for this to work it uses a rubric looking at key values of Named Ranges which are RubricItems, RatingsValuesRow, and RatingsColumn. I must use the named Ranges because the rubric could change at any given time. Bellow is the snippet of code I'm having issues with.

For this rubricItemC.value = 1 , subRubricItem = a , ratCell = 4

```
Dim ratingsCol As Range
Dim ratingsVal As Range
Dim rubricItem As Range
Dim rubricItemC As Range
Dim subRubricItem As Range
Dim gradeCount As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim ratCount As Range
Dim ratCell As Range

count = 0
gradeCount = 0
Set rubricItem = Workbooks(strRubricTemplateFilename).Worksheets(RubricSheet).Range("RubricItems")
Set ratingsVal = Workbooks(strRubricTemplateFilename).Worksheets(RubricSheet).Range("RatingsValuesRow")
Set ratingsCol = Workbooks(strRubricTemplateFilename).Worksheets(RubricSheet).Range("RatingsColumn")

'populates the ratings values which consist of [X,1,2,3,4]
For Each c In ratingsVal.Cells
    If Not (c.Value = "") Then
    gradeValuesDict.Add c.Value, gradeCount
    End If
Next

'iterates through each item in the rubric
For Each c In rubricItem.Cells
    Set rubricItemC = c
    Set ratCell = Cells(rubricItemC.Row, ratingsCol.Column)
    Set subRubricItem = rubricItemC.offset(0, 1)

    'checks to see if the dictionary exist if not create it.
    If Not dict.Exists(rubricItemC.Value) Then
        'adds to the dictionary passing another dictionary as the item.
        dict.Add rubricItemC.Value, subRubricDict
    End If

    'checks to see if the sub dictionary exists if not create it.
    If Not dict.Item(rubricItemC.Value).Exists(subRubricItem.Value) Then
        dict.Item(rubricItemC.Value).Add subRubricItem.Value, gradeValuesDict
    End If
      dict.Item(rubricItemC.Value).Item(subRubricItem).Item(ratCell) = dict.Item(rubricItemC.Value).Item(subRubricItem).Item(ratCell) + 1
Next
```

This is where I am getting my Object Required Error.

```
dict.Item(rubricItemC.Value).Item(subRubricItem).Item(ratCell) = dict.Item(rubricItemC.Value).Item(subRubricItem).Item(ratCell) + 1
```

I'm fairly new to VBA but what Im attempting to do here is reference the gradeCount within the multiple levels of dictionarys and increase the value by 1.

Comment: You have a `"` alone in the middle of the line, is it supposed to be here? (with one other, because there can't be only one)

Comment: Your line of error has in the code many double-quotes that do nor appear in your comment. `"rubricItemC.Value"` is not same as `rubricItemC.Value`. `"ratCell"` is not the same as `ratCell`... What is the actual statement in your code?

Comment: I've actually tried both neither work both returning the exact same error I'm not entirely sure which syntax is correct though. @A.S.H

Comment: I guess you need to remove those useless double-quotes anyway. They dont make any sense in view of your code. Please edit the code and test the correct version so that we can focus on the problem.

Comment: @A.S.H just removed them the code should reflect exactly as its in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dictionary object accepts *object references* as keys. For this reason, when you enter an item with some `Range object` as a key, you cannot retrieve the same item using the `range's value` as key, it will not find it. The same applies if you add an item with value and try to retrieve it by the range object (reference).

As a general rule, if your key in `.Add` is a `Range`, use the same range object as a key in `.Item`. On the other hand, if your key in `.Add` is a `Range.Value` (this is what you actually want to do), use the same `value` as a key in `.Item`.

```
dict.Item(rubricItemC.Value).Item(subRubricItem.Value).Item(ratCell.Value) = dict.Item(rubricItemC.Value).Item(subRubricItem.Value).Item(ratCell.Value) + 1
```

Comment: great! this worked perfectly im not sure why I wasn't referencing sub/ratCell values originally even though I did it for rubricItemC

Comment: the *default property* paradigm is a source of error in many situations, one of them was the one you encountered. Great to know the problem is solved :)

Comment: @user2062443 - Please mark as answered if this worked for you :)